# Stacking photo and content on top of one another in css media query

Tags: html, css

Would greatly appreciate any help! Thank you in advance!

I am coding a website and there is a portion whereby I have a picture and paragraphs of words align side by side. However, when I am adding media query, both of these elements don't seem to stack on top of one another. I would like them to stack on top of one another so that it will be easier for the reader to view on smaller screens. Here is the code.

```css
/* Flex Columns */
.flex-columns .row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.flex-columns .column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  flex: 1;
}

.flex-columns .column .column-1,
.flex-columns .column .column-2 {
  height: 100%;
}

.flex-columns img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.flex-columns .column-2 {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #28a745;
  color: white;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 30px;
}

.flex-columns h2 {
  font-size: 35px;
}

.flex-columns p {
  font-size: 20px;
```

Please help me :( I cannot seem to get the photos and the paragraphs to stack on top of one another In css media queries. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try by adding `display:block` for `row` in media query

```css
/* Flex Columns */
.flex-columns .row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.flex-columns .column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  flex: 1;
}

.flex-columns .column .column-1,
.flex-columns .column .column-2 {
  height: 100%;
}

.flex-columns img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.flex-columns .column-2 {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #28a745;
  color: white;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 30px;
}

.flex-columns h2 {
  font-size: 35px;
}

.flex-columns p {
  font-size: 20px;
  }

 /* media query for max width 600px screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
 .flex-columns .row {
  display: block;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}
}
```

```html
<!-- About 1st Part-->
      <section id= "about" class="about flex-columns">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="column">
            <div class="column-1">
              <img src="/My_website/image/ILSCM.JPG" alt="" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="column">
            <div class="column-2">
              <p> XXXXXXYYYYYY
                <br><br>
                 XXXXYYYYYYYYY
               </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Dinesh. I have added display:block in the media query but it is not working as well.. Thank you for your help!

Comment: but adding block  is working for me i adding image in answer for your reference please check